# How to increase canvas of an image?

Tags: android, image

I am looking for a way to increase the imagesize without stretching the original image, just add white pixels as border, similar to change canvas size in an image editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scaleType: CENTER in your ImageView to avoid scaling and set IMageView's background to @color/white. Then if you need to change the size of your image view, just update it's width and height, either in your layout XML or programmatically:

```
image_view.getLayoutParams().height = yourNewHeight;
image_view.getLayoutParams().width = yourNewWidth;
image_view.requestLayout()
```

Hope, this'll help. Cheers.